# How can I auto run py.test once a relative command has been change?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Via autonose or nosy, it will automatically run the nosetests once the some tests file or the relative files have been changes. I would like to ask that whether py.test provides the similar function for is there any other tools can automatically excite py.test.

Comment: I would highly recommend editor plugins for this. Emacs has pytest-emacs (https://bitbucket.org/antocuni/pytest-emacs) and I wrote pytest.vim (https://github.com/alfredodeza/pytest.vim) both allow you to interact easily and fast with py.test

Comment: It's cool! But I'm afraid that I cannot use it directly since I'm using tox to automatically build up a clean environment for test and execute the py.test via tox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install the [pytest-xdist plugin](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-xdist) and issue:

```
$ py.test --looponfail <filename>
```

You can also set the "looponfailroots" ini-file option to direct the plugin where to look for changes.

Comment: Just tried this and it seems the option has changed slightly. Now it's `$ py.test --looponfail`