# Running pytest repeatedly on changed test files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I want to run pytest multiple times from within Python without restarting the script/interpreter.

The problem is that pytest is caching test contents/results. That is, if you modify a test file between two runs, pytest doesn't pick up the changes, showing the same results as before. (Unless you restart the script/exit the interpreter, which you'd naturally do when using pytest from the command line.)

### Reproduction

`test_foo.py`:

```
def test_me():
    assert False
```

In the Python shell:

```
>>> import pytest
>>> pytest.main(['test_foo.py'])
(...)
    def test_me():
>       assert False
E       assert False

test_foo.py:2: AssertionError
```

Good so far. Now don't exit the interpreter but change the test to `assert True` and re-run pytest.

```
>>> pytest.main(['test_foo.py'])
(...)
    def test_me():
>       assert True
E       assert False

test_foo.py:2: AssertionError
```

### Expected result

Pytest should have picked up the change in the file and pass the rewritten test.

### Solutions that don't work

- Using `importlib.reload(pytest)` to reload pytest between the runs.
- Running pytest with cleared caches: `pytest.main(['--cache-clear', test_foo.py'])`

(Running pytest as a subprocess isn't an option because I want have a reference to the pytest module from within my application.)

Any hints how to make pytest pick up these changes or how to properly reload the module?

Comment: Not valuable enough to post this as an answer, but nevertheless: reloading `pytest` is not enough as all the other imported submodules (especially the undescored ones) still remain in `sys.modules`. I had this issue once in `ipython` and could solve it with the [`%autoreload` magic command](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html) (in the `ipython` shell, execute `%load_ext autoreload`, then `%autoreload 2`). If you need the builtin interactive shell, I guess you could manually try the `superreload` call that `autoreload` executes under the hood.

Comment: @hoefling Thanks, I am not really looking for a solution in the interactive shell. I simply have a Python script that repeatedly runs tests and should be able to pick up when the tests change.

Comment: Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12365707/1736679) that may help

Answer (score 2):

Anyone landing here, another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12365707/1736679) that may help, just install `pytest-xdist` plugin, and call `pytest --looponfail`

Comment: Trying to run `pytest.main()` in a loop and due to some hidden caching that happens my tests on the second run were failing. Using xdist + `pytest.main([dir, "-n", "auto"])` worked. Thanks!